# Docker - apt-get update not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

I am not able to build my Dockerfile without the following error:

*/bin/sh: 1: apt-get update : not found*

I am able to start a container using the `docker run` command, with no problems and can run `apt-get update` using `docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash`

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get update
```

Building using:

```
docker build -t demo/app  .
```

Comment: I don't think what you have outlined matches up. Could you post (copy and paste shell) your entire build log failure from the command you ran? I plugged in your dockerfile and ran the build command which worked successfully). The base ubuntu image you are using has `apt-get`. Not sure how you got that error.

Comment: It was a spacing issue.. quite weird. I retyped the whole file and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `apt-get update` as an argument to bash in docker run command.

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 bash -c "apt-get update"
```

To work with this

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install Packages
RUN apt-get update
```

You need to build it first, then tag it and run it.

```
docker build -t demo/app  .
```

After build you do not need to update for now

```
docker run --rm -it demo/app bash
```